# Is there a jQuery slider (as in Coda) plugin which handles forms on multiple panels and validates on submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, forms, slider

I've seen this:

[Codrops - fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/)

which is beautiful, bit a little overkill for my needs.

I basically need a jQuery slider which can have multiple panels each making up one form (each panel will likely only have multiple checkboxes) which can then be validated and the 'answers' reported in the last panel. It's a bit like an assessment / quiz where the correctness is reported on the last panel.

Thanks for all responses - I just can't seem to find one and am running out of time to code my own one up...

Comment: this example is excellent and beautiful as you say, if it's an overkill why dont you "water it down" until it fills you need? easier than building one yourself...

Comment: It's just that my requirements are SO much less than this code requires - it's a case of hitting a nut with a massive hammer! Thanks though...